# Cypress how to find an object in an array of object

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to call an API (/users) and check if a specific user exists.

```
describe('GET users', () => {
    it('find user', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://localhost:3000/api/users"
        })
        .should((response) => {
            expect(response.body.code).to.equal(200);
            cy.log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
            response.body.data.forEach(user => {
                cy.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                expect(user.name).to.equal("John");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But when I do that I expecting that all user has the name "John", this is wrong. How can I iterate and check if exists an user with name "John"?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?